# How to create enum like type in TypeScript?

Tags: enums, typescript

I'm working on a definitions file for the Google maps API for TypeScript.

And I need to define an enum like type eg. `google.maps.Animation` which contains two properties: `BOUNCE` and `DROP`.

How should this be done in TypeScript?

Comment: The Google Maps v3 definition is now complete and can be found on [Github](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) and [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/google.maps.d.ts)

Comment: Funny how all the answers below are wrong... in the following sense: `Enum Member name X must match one of the following formats: camelCase eslint(@typescript-eslint/naming-convention)`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

TypeScript 0.9+ has a specification for enums:

```
enum AnimationType {
    BOUNCE,
    DROP,
}
```

The final comma is optional.

Comment: I would advise against using the `enum` construct at this stage as the TypeScript team has made it pretty clear it is going to change - so it will break.

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools, for example with code you add to your answer. I changed it in your answer for, take a look please. Also please leave some reference if there is a related discussion about that language feature.

Comment: enum Animation { BOUNCE=1, DROP }, since that's how Maps API defines them.

Comment: FYI, [TypeScript 0.9 includes a finalized design for enums](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/06/18/announcing-typescript-0-9.aspx)

Comment: as 10 years later from the last update here, just want to point out that the advise against using `enum` above is no longer valid since Typescript is totally supporting this. [Typescript enum docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Answer (score 70):

As of TypeScript 0.9 (currently an alpha release) you can use the enum definition like this:

```
enum TShirtSize {
  Small,
  Medium,
  Large
}

var mySize = TShirtSize.Large;
```

By default, these enumerations will be assigned 0, 1 and 2 respectively. If you want to explicitly set these numbers, you can do so as part of the enum declaration.

Listing 6.2 Enumerations with explicit members

```
enum TShirtSize {
  Small = 3,
  Medium = 5,
  Large = 8
}

var mySize = TShirtSize.Large;
```

Both of these examples lifted directly out of [TypeScript for JavaScript Programmers](https://leanpub.com/typescriptbook).

**Note that this is different to the 0.8 specification.** The 0.8 specification looked like this - but it was marked as experimental and likely to change, so you'll have to update any old code:

**Disclaimer** - this 0.8 example would be broken in newer versions of the TypeScript compiler.

```
enum TShirtSize {
  Small: 3,
  Medium: 5,
  Large: 8
}

var mySize = TShirtSize.Large;
```

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer since it is still working in the RC and is therefore unlikely to break with future versions of TS.

Answer (score 31):

This is now part of the language. See [TypeScriptLang.org > Basic Types > enum](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-enum) for the documentation on this. An excerpt from the documentation on how to use these enums:

```
enum Color {Red, Green, Blue};
var c: Color = Color.Green;
```

Or with manual backing numbers:

```
enum Color {Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4};
var c: Color = Color.Green;
```

You can also go back to the enum name by using for example `Color[2]`.

Here's an example of how this all goes together:

```
module myModule {
    export enum Color {Red, Green, Blue};

    export class MyClass {
        myColor: Color;

        constructor() {
            console.log(this.myColor);
            this.myColor = Color.Blue;
            console.log(this.myColor);
            console.log(Color[this.myColor]);
        }
    }
}

var foo = new myModule.MyClass();
```

This will log:

> ```
> undefined  
> 2  
> Blue
> ```

Because, at the time of writing this, the Typescript Playground will generate this code:

```javascript
var myModule;
(function (myModule) {
    (function (Color) {
        Color[Color["Red"] = 0] = "Red";
        Color[Color["Green"] = 1] = "Green";
        Color[Color["Blue"] = 2] = "Blue";
    })(myModule.Color || (myModule.Color = {}));
    var Color = myModule.Color;
    ;
    var MyClass = (function () {
        function MyClass() {
            console.log(this.myColor);
            this.myColor = Color.Blue;
            console.log(this.myColor);
            console.log(Color[this.myColor]);
        }
        return MyClass;
    })();
    myModule.MyClass = MyClass;
})(myModule || (myModule = {}));
var foo = new myModule.MyClass();
```

Answer (score 14):

Just another note that you can a id/string enum with the following:

```
class EnumyObjects{
    public static BOUNCE={str:"Bounce",id:1};
    public static DROP={str:"Drop",id:2};
    public static FALL={str:"Fall",id:3};


}
```

Comment: How would you access their `str` and `id` using that?

Comment: EnumyObjects.BOUNCE.str would access the value.

Comment: The problem with this design is that the objects are all mutable, which could cause problems: http://goo.gl/CT4Ip

Comment: Would `abstract class` be more appropriate to prevent instantiation since TypeScript doesn't have a notion of a `static class`?

Answer (score 13):

**Update**:

As noted by @iX3, **Typescript 2.4** has support for enum strings.

See:[Create an enum with string values in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript#answer-15491832)

---

**Original answer:**

For String member values, TypeScript only allows numbers as enum member values. But there are a few solutions/hacks you can implement;

**Solution 1:**

copied from: https://blog.rsuter.com/how-to-implement-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript/

There is a simple solution: Just cast the string literal to any before assigning:

```
export enum Language {
    English = <any>"English",
    German = <any>"German",
    French = <any>"French",
    Italian = <any>"Italian"
}
```

**solution 2:**

copied from: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/literal-types.html

You can use a string literal as a type. For example:

```
let foo: 'Hello';
```

Here we have created a variable called foo that will only allow the literal value 'Hello' to be assigned to it. This is demonstrated below:

```
let foo: 'Hello';
foo = 'Bar'; // Error: "Bar" is not assignable to type "Hello"
```

They are not very useful on their own but can be combined in a type union to create a powerful (and useful) abstraction e.g.:

```
type CardinalDirection =
    "North"
    | "East"
    | "South"
    | "West";

function move(distance: number, direction: CardinalDirection) {
    // ...
}

move(1,"North"); // Okay
move(1,"Nurth"); // Error!
```

Comment: TypeScript 2.4 includes support for string literal types in enums. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript#answer-15491832 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/#string-enums

Answer (score 3):

### Enums in typescript:

Enums are put into the typescript language to define a set of named constants. Using enums can make our life easier. The reason for this is that these constants are often easier to read than the value which the enum represents.

### Creating a enum:

```
enum Direction {
    Up = 1,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
}
```

This example from the typescript docs explains very nicely how enums work. Notice that our first enum value (Up) is initialized with 1. All the following members of the number enum  are then **auto incremented** from this value (i.e. Down = 2, Left = 3, Right = 4). If we didn't initialize the first value with 1 the enum would start at 0 and then auto increment (i.e. Down = 1, Left = 2, Right = 3).

### Using an enum:

We can access the values of the enum in the following manner:

```
Direction.Up;     // first the enum name, then the dot operator followed by the enum value
Direction.Down;
```

Notice that this way we are much more **descriptive** in the way we write our code. Enums basically prevent us from using **magic numbers** (numbers which represent some entity because the programmer has given a meaning to them in a certain context). Magic numbers are bad because of the following reasons:

1. We need to think harder, we first need to translate the number to an entity before we can reason about our code.
2. If we review our code after a long while, or other programmers review our code, they don't necessarily know what is meant with these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me to type enums like this (which also allows you to loop through it as an object):

```
enum: { [x: string]: string }
```

Map example:

```
export const yourFunction = (
  enum: { [x: string]: string },
 ) => { 
  const iHaveBeenMapped = Object.keys(enum).map((key) => {
   const enumValue = enum[key];
  }); 
 }
```