# How to require a specific string in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a TypeScript definition file for a 3rd party js library. One of the methods allows for an options object, and one of the properties of the options object accepts a string from the list: `"collapse"`, `"expand"`, `"end-expand"`, and `"none"`.

I have an interface for the options object:

```
interface IOptions {
  indent_size?: number;
  indent_char?: string;
  brace_style?: // "collapse" | "expand" | "end-expand" | "none"
}
```

Can the interface enforce this, so if you include an `IOptions` object with the `brace_style` property, it will only allow a string that is in the acceptable list?

Comment: Please revisit the answers to this question

Comment: Kinda along the lines of the comment from @Andreas , why do you prefer RyanQ's answer over  [Denis Khay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45801281/1028230)? Denis' seems more broadly applicable imo.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

This was released in version 1.8 as "string literal types"

[What's New in Typescript - String Literal Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#string-literal-types)

Example from the page:

```
interface AnimationOptions {
  deltaX: number;
  deltaY: number;
  easing: "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
}
```

Comment: It requires copying and pasting line with strings wherever in app you would need to pass string of this type as an argument. If you are always using whole AnimationOptions that solution seems ok, but for use cases when you may only pass 'easing' type it is wrong. See Denis Khay answer, it is far better.

Comment: [TypeScript Docs: Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)

Answer (score 354):

Try this

```
export type ReadingTypes = 'some'|'variants'|'of'|'strings';

export interface IReadings {
   param:ReadingTypes
}
```

Edit: Many thanks for upvotes, but, as time passed and me evolved as a developer :), now in most of the cases I wouldn't recommend this approach anymore. Yes it still valid but the point is the construction above is very similar to enum structure so why not use enum instead (advantages below):

```
export enum ReadingTypes {
    Some = 'some',
    Variants = 'variants',
    Of = 'of',
    Strings = 'strings',
}
export interface IReadings {
   param: ReadingTypes
}
```

Advantages: (Yes, might be it is more like IMHO, I understand, but, nonetheless)

1. It is more readable when you see it in the code, for example

```
if(item.reading === 'some') {
...
}
// vs 
if(item.reading === ReadingTypes.Some) {
...
}
```

In first case when you read the code you could not catch, from the first glance, that .reading field can only contain few certain params, and not like, any string value.

2. When you write the code you will have better assistance of your editor if you use enums - it is enough to remember name of enum and write it and it will show you all variants of enum. Yeah, with the first type ('some' | 'variants' ... ) it can do so too, but it does it less.. um.. eagerly

Comment: This should be marked as correct, because it allows reusing created type anywhere in an application.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for as a way to pass an array of strings as values to an enumerated type. By skipping over enum completely and using `type`, I was able to pass the following example: `const myVar: ReadingTypes = ["some"|"variants"];` while still maintaining a dynamic enum typing syntax. Completely agreed that this should have been the answer marked as correct.

Comment: is there a way to use this but softly typed like this `type VisibilityTypes =  VISIBILITY.PUBLISH | VISBIBILITY.DRAFT` I get a namespace not found error, however when I hard code them it seems to work

Comment: I found a way, and added a new answer

Comment: i tried first to equal the type to say 'json' | 'text' and it did not work but when i set it to be say ResponseType and then did type ResponseType = 'json' | 'text' it did work, thank you!

Comment: This is not working for me. In my case I want to restrict various properties values of an object, but I can only use "param:" once. :/ How can I add more restricted string properties to my object? There's not much about the 'param' reserved word in TS.

Answer (score 26):

TS offers a typing to specific string values, which are called **String literal types**.

Here is an example of how to use them:

```
type style =  "collapse" | "expand" | "end-expand" | "none";

interface IOptions {
  indent_size?: number;
  indent_char?: string;
  brace_style1?:  "collapse" | "expand" | "end-expand" | "none";
  brace_style2?:  style;
}

// Ok
let obj1: IOptions = {brace_style1: 'collapse'};

// Compile time error:
// Type '"collapsessss"' is not assignable to type '"collapse" | "expand" | "end-expand" | "none" | undefined'.
let obj2: IOptions = {brace_style1: 'collapsessss'};
```

Answer (score 15):

## In TypeScript 2.4 onward you can use [String Enums](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/string-enums-in-typescript)

I favour this approach because it avoids the need to have the same hard coded string in more than one place.

Its possible to make an enum where the values are strings

```
export enum VISIBILITY {
  PUBLISH = "publish",
  DRAFT = "draft"
}
```

This enum can then be used as a type on an interface or class

```
export interface UserOptions  {
  visibility:  VISIBILITY 
}
```

Comment: BTW all caps reduces readability https://accessibility.huit.harvard.edu/design-readability

Answer (score 10):

Maybe not exactly what you wanted, but `Enum`s seem like a perfect solution for you.

```
enum BraceStyle {Collapse, Expand, EndExpand, None}

interface IOptions {
  indent_size?: number;
  indent_char?: string;
  brace_style?: BraceStyle
}
```

Enums are, however, number-based. It means that during runtime a real value for e.g. `BraceStyle.Collapse` will be 0 in this case. But you can use them with other, even non-typescript scripts, since they compile to objects. This is how `BraceStyle` will look after compile&run:

```
{
    0: "Collapse",
    1: "Expand",
    2: "EndExpand",
    3: "None",
    Collapse: 0,
    Expand: 1,
    EndExpand: 2,
    None: 3
}
```

If you want strings instead, you can use a class with static members, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491832/2148667)

Comment: `enum`s can have string values (now at least, not sure if they could in 2014). `enum BraceStyle { Collapse = "Collapse", Expand = "Expand" }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function keysOf<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) { return obj[key]; }
interface SomeInterface {
   a: string;
}
const instance: SomeInterface = { a: 'some value'};
let value = keysOf<SomeInterface>(instance, 'b'); // invalid
value =  keysOf<SomeInterface>(instance, 'a'); // valid
```

Answer (score 1):

`enum` is probably the best solution, but if you have your values as keys of a const object and you can't change that, the syntax would be

```
brace_style?: typeof BRACE_STYLES[keyof typeof BRACE_STYLES];
```

where `BRACE_STYLES` is the name of the const object

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want the `enum` options. **But if you do not, and you really need your `const` to exist**, the `keyOf` that some answers post here works, with a slight modification:

```
export const BRACE_STYLES = {
  collapse: 'collapse',
  'end-expand': 'end-expand',
  expand: 'expand',
  none: 'none'
}

export type BraceStyle = keyof typeof BRACE_STYLES

export interface IOptions {
  indent_size?: number
  indent_char?: string
  brace_style?: BraceStyle
}
```

This will actually get you the `"collapse" | "expand" | "end-expand" | "none"` effect you want, still allow the `const` to exists, without the need of hardcoding the type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type as stated by others.
I would add to that, that you can also infer that created type from an object const:

```
export const braceStyles = {
  collapse: "collapse",
  expand: "expand",
  end-expand: "end-expand",
  none: "none"
}

export type braceStyle = typeof braceStyles[keyof typeof braceStyles]

export interface IOptions {
  indent_size?: number;
  indent_char?: string;
  brace_style?: bracestyle;
}
```

That way you don't have to use enum and you can also use the object properties everywhere you need them, where they will be of type string, not type enum.member

[objects vs enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit broad but can be extended to many use cases.
You would make use of `MappedTypes`.

Here's an use case:

```
// Let's say that you have different string literals defining a 'type' property
// i.e: 'text' | 'video' | 'image' […]
// You would like each 'type' to 'enable' or 'disable' different   
// properties based on the `type` property:
const fooObj: MyObject = {
    type: "foo",
    value: {
        sharedProp: "shared",
        fooProperty1: 123,
        fooProperty2: "hello"
    }
};

const barObj: MyObject = {
    type: "bar",
    value: {
        sharedProp: "shared",
        barProperty1: true,
        barProperty2: new Date()
    }
};



type CommonProps = {
    sharedProp: "shared";
};

type FooProperties = {
    fooProperty1: number;
    fooProperty2: string;
    // ... other foo properties
};

type BarProperties = {
    barProperty1: boolean;
    barProperty2: Date;
    // ... other bar properties
};

type AllProperties = {
    foo: FooProperties,
    bar: BarProperties,
    // ... other discriminators and their properties
};

type MyObject = {
    [K in keyof AllProperties]: {
        type: K;
        value: AllProperties[K] & CommonProps;
    };
}[keyof AllProperties];
```