# Typescript Cipher.getAuthTag doesn't exists

Tags: node.js, typescript, encryption

I am trying to do encrypt/decrypt using this https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples but the `Cipher` definition doesn't have `getAuthTag`.

is there a @types should I install?

**EDIT**
Just saw node/index.d.ts the `getAuthTag` and `setAAD` is is commented. I don't think it is right to remove the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to [the declaration of `Cipher` in `@types/node`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8f7b983d5076174f520f53acc7041d6a779af7fe/types/node/index.d.ts#L5918-L5938), you'll notice that it has subinterfaces that have `getAuthTag`:

```
    export interface Cipher extends NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {
        update(data: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView): Buffer;
        update(data: string, input_encoding: Utf8AsciiBinaryEncoding): Buffer;
        update(data: Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, output_encoding: HexBase64BinaryEncoding): string;
        update(data: Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, input_encoding: any, output_encoding: HexBase64BinaryEncoding): string;
        // second arg ignored
        update(data: string, input_encoding: Utf8AsciiBinaryEncoding, output_encoding: HexBase64BinaryEncoding): string;
        final(): Buffer;
        final(output_encoding: string): string;
        setAutoPadding(auto_padding?: boolean): this;
        // getAuthTag(): Buffer;
        // setAAD(buffer: Buffer): this; // docs only say buffer
    }
    export interface CipherCCM extends Cipher {
        setAAD(buffer: Buffer, options: { plaintextLength: number }): this;
        getAuthTag(): Buffer;
    }
    export interface CipherGCM extends Cipher {
        setAAD(buffer: Buffer, options?: { plaintextLength: number }): this;
        getAuthTag(): Buffer;
}
```

And [`createCipheriv` has corresponding overloads](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8f7b983d5076174f520f53acc7041d6a779af7fe/types/node/index.d.ts#L5914-L5916):
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/index.d.ts#L5914-L5916

```
export function createCipheriv(algorithm: CipherCCMTypes, key: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, iv: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, options: CipherCCMOptions): CipherCCM;
export function createCipheriv(algorithm: CipherGCMTypes, key: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, iv: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, options?: CipherGCMOptions): CipherGCM;
export function createCipheriv(algorithm: string, key: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, iv: string | Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView, options?: stream.TransformOptions): Cipher;
```

So if you pass an `algorithm` argument that is *known at compile time* to belong to `CipherGCMTypes`, then you should be able to call `getAuthTag`.  If it's not working, please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the issue you're having is because you're defining the algorithm as a string and it should be Cipher.CipherGCMTypes.

When you define the variable you declare the type. As Matt said, you have to pass it in as that type.

```
private ALGORITHM:crypto.CipherGCMTypes = 'aes-256-gcm';
let cipher:crypto.Cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(this.ALGORITHM, Buffer.from(this.encryptionKeyMessage, 'base64'), iv)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains the "why" well. This answer is for those facing the issue and wondering what to try.

I faced this today. In my case, the algorithm was a variable that was resolved at runtime. The code below worked.

```
private algorithm: "aes-256-gcm" | "aes-128-gcm"; //see link below
//some code
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
  this.algorithm,
  Buffer.from(rawKey, "hex"),
  Buffer.from(iv)
);
```

TypeScript compiled this without issues.

References: [How to require a specific string in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855423/how-to-require-a-specific-string-in-typescript-interface)