# How to define a new type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Let say I have a variable with the following type:

```
let weekDay: 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Thu' | 'Fri' | 'Sat';
```

And in different places in my project I'm using this type, so each time I write:

```
function setDay(day: 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Thu' | 'Fri' | 'Sat') { ... }
function getDay(): 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Thu' | 'Fri' | 'Sat' { ... }
```

How can I define this new type once, so I will not need to write it each time. I try to define an `interface` but it will create an object-type with this type as one of each attributes, but this **isn't** what I want

```
interface iWeekDay {
  day: 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Thu' | 'Fri' | 'Sat';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to require a specific string in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855423/how-to-require-a-specific-string-in-typescript-interface)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define it as:

```
type DayOfWeek = 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Thu' | 'Fri' | 'Sat';

function setDay(day: DayOfWeek) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a new type in the same file as your interface such as:

```
export interface IWeekDay {
    day: dayType;
}

export type dayType =
| "Sun"
| "Mon"
| "Tue"
| "Wed"
| "Thu"
| "Fri"
| "Sat";
```

By doing so, you export a `IWeekDay` interface that has one param of type `dayType`.