# In ts, I want the parameter of a function to be either a or b, for example:

Tags: typescript

In ts, I want the parameter of a function to be either a or b, for example:

```
let func = (str) => {}
// str can only be equal to one of'top' and'end'
```

I have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to require a specific string in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855423/how-to-require-a-specific-string-in-typescript-interface)

Comment: function HelloWorld(str:string|number){
    console.log("HELLO ", str)
}

Answer (score 1):

```js
let func = (str: 'top' | 'end') => {};
```

You are looking for [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) in combination with [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types).

Answer (score 0):

```
 type Flow = {
    top: string,
    end: string
 }
let func = (str: keyof Flow) => {}
```