# typescript one liner string declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const abc = (str: string) => str
```

How do restrict string to specified value like 'a' and 'b' only?

I know it can be an enum but I want to make it one liner

Comment: Why do you want to make it a one liner? Code clarity is more important than concision. Just use enum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to require a specific string in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855423/how-to-require-a-specific-string-in-typescript-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to make a string like that you can do

```
const abc:'a'|'b' = 'a'
```