# Enum to constrain string values

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to constrain the acceptable string values for a property on an interface. The intuitive way was to use an enum which was confirmed after googling around in posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855423/how-to-require-a-specific-string-in-typescript-interface). But when iterating over the enum to populate that property of the interface I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'EventTypes | undefined'`.

Code:

```
export enum EventTypes {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
  ...
}

export interface GetEventsParams {
  event_type?: EventTypes;
  ...
}

for (const toDate of dates) {
    for (const eventType in EventTypes) {
      params.push({
        fromDate,
        toDate,
        baseParams: { event_type: eventType }
      })
    }
  }
```

Is there a different way to iterate over the EventTypes values that makes typescript recognize its one of EventTypes? What's the recommended way to accomplish this?

PS:
One way to make it stop complaining, adding `{ event_type: eventType as EventTypes }`, seems hacky but is this the recommended way to solve the issue. And I'd rather not duplicate the strings into a type like `"value" | "value2"` seeing as I use the enum elsewhere and having to change values in multiple locations instead of just once in the enum is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using enums in typescript. Generally you want to use types

```js
type Gender = "male" | "female";
```

alternatively use [const enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) if you need number values.

Comment: What's the reason you suggest avoiding enums?

Comment: because enums exists during runtime, which you dont need 99% of the time in typescript.