# Interface of a status option

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I'm trying to write an interface for a status option in my `Props` interface. See code below

```js
interface Props {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  show: boolean;
  status: Status;
}

interface Status {
  warning: string;
  error: string;
  info: string;
  success: string;
}
```

However, I know this isn't the correct implementation. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for here:
[How to require a specific string in TypeScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855423/how-to-require-a-specific-string-in-typescript-interface)

In my case it meant

```
interface Props {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  show: boolean;
  status: "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning";
}
```