# Workaround for string based enums in typescript

Tags: typescript

So I found a suggestion that in typescript you can have string-based enums using this syntax:

```
export enum TextAlign {
    Left = <any>"start",
    Right = <any>"end",
    Center = <any>"middle"
}
```

Are there any drawbacks of using this approach?

There is a suggestion to use String Literal Type instead, although I find the enum more comfortable, as you can iterate through values.

Comment: The answers on http://stackoverflow.com/q/15490560/215552 have a lot of detail about using string-based enums. Is your question answered by those? Also, it does not appear as though you're asking for a workaround as your title suggests, but rather what the drawbacks are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any drawbacks of using this approach?

Safety e.g.

```
let x:number = TextAlign.Left; // compiles fine but actually you just assigned a string to number
```

## More

Every time you assert you are potentially lying to the compiler : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html and these lies tend to catch up :)

## More More

String literal types are generally preferred : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html