# Typescript String Based Enums

Tags: json, string, typescript, enums, code-completion

So I've read all the posts on String Based Enums in Typescript, but I couldn't find a solution that meets my requirements. Those would be:

- Enums that provide code completion
- Enums that can be iterated over
- Not having to specify an element twice
- String based

The possibilities I've seen so far for enums in typescript are:

1. `enum MyEnum {bla, blub}`: This fails at being string based, so I can't simply read from JSONs which are string based...
2. `type MyEnum = 'bla' | 'blub'`: Not iterable and no code completion
3. Do it yourself `class MyEnum { static get bla():string{return "bla"} ; static get blub():string{return "blub"}}`: Specifies elements twice

So here come the questions:

1. There's no way to satisfy those requirements simultaneously? If no, will it be possible in the future?
2. Why didn't they make `enums` string based?
3. Did someone experience similar problems and how did you solve them?

Comment: Please see [TypeScript docs for String Based Enums](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/stringEnums.html). Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript) post might help you out.

Comment: Can you give an example of code which couldn't "simply read from JSONs which are string based"?

Comment: **See Also**: [Create an enum with string values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15490560/1366033)

Answer (score 3):

I think that implementing `Enum` in a C-like style with numbers is fine, because an `Enum` (similar to a `Symbol`) is usually used to declare a value that is uniquely identifiable on development time. How the machine represents that value on run time doesn't really concern the developer.

**But** what we developer sometimes want (because we're all lazy and still want to have all the benefits!), is to use the `Enum` as an API or with an API that does not share that `Enum` with us, even though the API is essentially an `Enum` because the valid value of a property only is `foo` and `bar`.

I guess this is the reason why some languages have string based `Enums` :)

## How TypeScript handles Enums

If you look at the transpiled JavaScript you can see that TypeScript just uses a plain JavaScript Object to implement an `Enum`. For example:

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

will be transpiled to:

```
{
  0: "Red",
  1: "Green",
  2: "Blue",
  Blue: 2,
  Green: 1,
  Red: 0
}
```

This means you can access the string value like `Color[Color.Red]`. You will still have code completion and you do not have to specify the values twice. **But** you can not just do `Object.keys(Color)` to iterate over the `Enum`, because the values exist "twice" on the object.

Answer (score 2):

> Why didn't they make enums string based

To be clear Enums are both *number* and *string* based in that direct access is `number` and reverse map is `string` ([more on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html#enums-and-strings)).

## Meeting your requirement

You key reason for ruling out raw enums is

> so I can't simply read from JSONs which are string based...

You will experience the same thing e.g. when reading `Date`s cause JSON has no date data type. You would `new Date("someServerDateTime")` to convert these.

You would use the same strategy to go from server side `enum` (string) to TS `enum` (number). Easy done thanks to the reverse lookup `MyEnum["someServerString"]`

## Hydration

This process of converting server side data to client side *active* data is sometimes called Hydration. My favorite lib for this at the moment is https://github.com/pleerock/class-transformer

I personally handle this stuff myself at the *server access* level i.e. hand write an API that makes the XHR + does the serialization.

At my last job we automated this with code generation that did even more than that (supported common validation patterns between server and client code).

Comment: "Enums are both number and string" -> okay, but I'd like to do something like e.g. in angular `ng-if="myObject.type === 'bla'"`, which won't work, unless I do the hydration you mentioned. What I would prefer would be a purely string based enumeration of the enum, somewhat like the DIY class in the question. Are there advantages of having a mixed numer / string map for enums like in typescript?

Comment: I think you're trying to use language feature that doesn't solve your problem. But you can always implement a simple method to "implement" your string-based enums. Also, you could use TypeScript's Enum to use with `ng-if`. You just have to do `ng-if="myObject.type === TypeEnum.Bla"`

Comment: Sorry... Typo:  `ng-if="myObject.type === TypeEnum[TypeEnum.Bla]"`