# How to simulate a string based enum

Tags: typescript, enums, string-literals, typechecking

I have a value that comes from an API that could be either `"orange"`, `"apple"` or `"banana"`.

So first I created a type as:

`type Fruit = "orange" | "apple" | "banana";`

So then I can type the value from the API as `Fruit`;

```js
type Fruit = "orange" | "apple" | "banana";

function getFruitFromApi(): Fruit {
    // simulating random result
    const fruits: Fruit[] = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];

    return fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

const fruit: Fruit = getFruitFromApi();

switch (fruit) {
    case "orange": break;
    case "apple": break;
    case "banana": break;
}
```

That's okay but I'd like to avoid having to type those strings manually in the switch. I'd like to have something like `Fruit.Orange`, `Fruit.Apple` and `Fruit.Banana`. So basically like an enum but with the values matched with strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the answer from this old question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257367/105937

With TS 1.8 or later we can do the following:

```
type Fruit = "orange" | "apple" | "banana";

const Fruit = {
    Orange: "orange" as Fruit,
    Apple:  "apple" as Fruit,
    Banana: "banana"  as Fruit
};
```

And then use it as `Fruit.Orange` which will be resolved to `"orange"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the values of an enum, but if they are not numbers then the compiler won't like it.
You can cast to `any` to remove compilation errors:

```
enum Fruit {
    Orange = "orange" as any,
    Apple = "apple" as any,
    Banana = "banana" as any
}

function getFruitFromApi(): Fruit {
    const fruits = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];

    return fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] as any;
}
```

Another option is to use a regular enum and to convert the received string into that enum:

```
enum Fruit {
    Orange,
    Apple,
    Banana
}

function getFruitFromApi(): Fruit {
    const fruits = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];
    const fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

    for (var key in Fruit) {
        if (typeof key === "string" && key.toLowerCase() === fruit) {
            return (Fruit as any)[key];
        }
    }

    return null;
}

const fruit: Fruit = getFruitFromApi();

switch (fruit) {
    case Fruit.Orange:
        console.log("orange");
        break;
    case Fruit.Apple:
        console.log("apple");
        break;
    case Fruit.Banana:
        console.log("banana");
        break;
}
```