# TypeScript Mapped Type Key/Values

Tags: function, typescript, types, parameters, typemaps

I want to write a function with a parameter type guard that accepts the value from a K/V pair from an object or type...

```
type VodTreeName = {
  Movie: 'movie_vod',
  TV: 'tv_vod',
  VideoStore: 'video_store'
};

function test(something: VodTreeName) {
  // expecting something === 'movie_vod'
}

test(VodTreeName.Movie);
// 'VodTreeName' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

--or--

```
const VodTreeName = {
  Movie: 'movie_vod',
  TV: 'tv_vod',
  VideoStore: 'video_store'
};

function test(something: keyof typeof VodTreeName) {
  // expecting something === 'movie_vod'
}

test(VodTreeName.Movie);
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Movie" | "TV" | "VideoStore"'.
```

How else can I do this without having a type AND an object that I have to export/import to other modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a type alias in runtime, there's no js equivalent for that.

The `test` function in the 2nd snippet expects a key of `VodTreeName` but you are passing the value, it should be:

```
function test(key: keyof typeof VodTreeName) {
    console.log(VodTreeName[key]);
}

test("Movie");
```

If you want to use it like so:

```
test(VodTreeName.Movie);
```

Then you're basically looking for a string based enum, in which case check this thread: [Create an enum with string values in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript) and this issue: [Proposal: String enums](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3192).