# How to create an enum with typescript and returning string

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

guys i wanna ask if i can create an enum that looks like this

```
export enum CompanyMemberTypeEnum {
    DIRECTORS,
    SHAREHOLDERS,
    DIRECTORS_AND_SHAREHOLDERS
}
```

`CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS` will return 0 right ?
but how if i want to create a function that can get string of an enum like this

```
CompanyMemberTypeEnum.getList(CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS)
```

will return 'Directors'

in a enum file, is that possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an enum with string values in Typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a base `Enum<T>` class.

```
export class Enum<T> {
  public constructor(public readonly value: T) {}
  public toString() {
    return this.value.toString();
  }
}
```

Create your class that extends `Enum<T>`;

```
export class CompanyMemberTypeEnum extends Enum<string> {
  public static readonly DIRECTORS = new Enum('DIRECTORS');
  public static readonly SHAREHOLDERS= new Enum('SHAREHOLDERS');
  public static readonly DIRECTORS_AND_SHAREHOLDERS = new Enum('DIRECTORS_AND_SHAREHOLDERS');
}
```

now, you can use your enums like;

```
console.log(CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS); // Enum { value: 'DIRECTORS' }
console.log(CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS.value); // DIRECTORS
console.log(CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS.toString()); // DIRECTORS
```

Comment: can i make the enum that return `CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS // return 0` by default ?
and `CompanyMemberTypeEnum.DIRECTORS.getString() // return 'Directors' string` ?

and thanks for the answer ! :)

Answer (score 6):

Prior to `TypeScript 2.4`, TypeScript only supported number-based enums, but nowadays it is possible out of the box.
 A SO answer about it has been already provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values-in-typescript) as toskv pointed out.

As example:

```
enum BeerTypes {
   lager = "Lager",
   ipa = "IPA"
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You can define your enum like:

```
export enum CompanyMemberTypeEnum {
    DIRECTORS = <any>'Directors',
    SHAREHOLDERS = <any>'ShareHolders',
    DIRECTORS_AND_SHAREHOLDERS = <any>'Directors and shareholders'
}
```