# How do I limit values to keys of an object?

Tags: typescript

Assume I have the following:

```
export const ContentType = {
    Json: "application/json",
    Urlencoded: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Multipart: "multipart/form-data",
};

export interface RequestOptions {
    contentType: string,
}

const defaultOptions: Partial<RequestOptions> = {
    contentType: ContentType.Json,
};
```

How would I go about restricting `contentType` so that only keys declared in `ContentType` are used?

Comment: Don't you want to limit `contentType` to the values of `ContentType`, not the keys?

Comment: Looks like you might be able to use Lookup types like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41631732/215552)...

Answer (score 11):

This is my preferred way as of TypeScript 2.1:

```
export const contentTypes = {
    "application/json": true,
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": true,
    "multipart/form-data": true
};

type ContentType = keyof typeof contentTypes;

export interface RequestOptions {
    contentType: ContentType;
}

const defaultOptions: Partial<RequestOptions> = {
    contentType: "application/json",
};
```

[Try it in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20const%20contentTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22application%2Fjson%22%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%22%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22multipart%2Fform-data%22%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ContentType%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20contentTypes%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20RequestOptions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20contentType%3A%20ContentType%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20defaultOptions%3A%20Partial%3CRequestOptions%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20contentType%3A%20%22application%2Fjson%22%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B)

- Define a set of valid strings in an object literal.
- Create a type that contains the keys of that object, using `keyof`. It's a string union type.
- Type your string property to that union type, and the compiler will only allow those strings.

Comment: Can't believe I stumbled upon the famous Robert Penner in the wild! Just wanted to say I'm a huge fan.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types). Instead of typing `contentType` as `string`, type it as a literal type of possible values.

```
export interface RequestOptions {
    contentType: "application/json" | "multipart/form-data" | "multipart/form-data:"
}
```

To avoid repeating your constants you can declare them separately and type `contentType` as `typeof ConstantString`:

```
export const ContentTypeJson = "application/json";
export const ContentTypeUrlencoded = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
export const ContentTypeMultipart = "multipart/form-data";


export interface RequestOptions {
    contentType: typeof ContentTypeJson| typeof ContentTypeUrlencoded | typeof ContentTypeMultipart,
}

const defaultOptions: Partial<RequestOptions> = {
    contentType: ContentTypeJson,
};
```

Comment: Issue I have with this is that I'm just repeating the value everywhere.  While I get enforcement that only valid values are used, I'm still repeating them.

Comment: @Omega I have updated the answer with another approach where you don't have to repeat constants.