# How can a enum member be aliased in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have a below `enum` in TypeScript:

```js
enum RoleTypes {
  None,
  Admin,
  SuperAdmin
}
```

When I run the following code:

```js
var roleName = RoleTypes[RoleTypes.SuperAdmin];
```

the value of the variable `roleName` is `SuperAdmin`.

Is it possible to change it to a custom name `'Super Administrator'`, and how do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a seperate object or array for this ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20RoleTypes%20%7B%0D%0A%20None%2C%0D%0A%20Admin%2C%0D%0A%20SuperAdmin%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20RoleTypesDisplay%3A%20%7B%20%5Bindex%3A%20number%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0ARoleTypesDisplay%5BRoleTypes.None%5D%20%3D%20%22None%22%3B%0D%0ARoleTypesDisplay%5BRoleTypes.Admin%5D%20%3D%20%22Administrator%22%3B%0D%0ARoleTypesDisplay%5BRoleTypes.SuperAdmin%5D%20%3D%20%22Super%20Administrator%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20roleName%20%3D%20RoleTypesDisplay%5BRoleTypes.SuperAdmin%5D%3B%0D%0Aalert(roleName)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20because%20RoleTypes%20is%20a%20number%20based%20enum%20that%20starts%20with%200%20this%20is%20equals%20to%20%0D%0ARoleTypesDisplay%20%3D%20%5B%22None%22%2C%20%22Administrator%22%2C%20%22Super%20Administrator%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20roleName%20%3D%20RoleTypesDisplay%5BRoleTypes.SuperAdmin%5D%3B%0D%0Aalert(roleName)%3B)):

```
enum RoleTypes {
    None,
    Admin,
    SuperAdmin
}

let RoleTypesDisplay: { [index: number]: string } = {};
RoleTypesDisplay[RoleTypes.None] = "None";
RoleTypesDisplay[RoleTypes.Admin] = "Administrator";
RoleTypesDisplay[RoleTypes.SuperAdmin] = "Super Administrator";

var roleName = RoleTypesDisplay[RoleTypes.SuperAdmin];
alert(roleName);

// because RoleTypes is a number based enum that starts with 0 this is equals to 
RoleTypesDisplay = ["None", "Administrator", "Super Administrator"];

var roleName = RoleTypesDisplay[RoleTypes.SuperAdmin];
alert(roleName);
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, simply create an alias using a quoted identifier

```
enum RoleTypes {
 None,
 Admin,
 SuperAdmin,
 'Super Administrator' = SuperAdmin 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As of TypeScript 2.4 [you can assign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257367/7946224) string values directly to enum members

```
enum RoleTypes{
  None = "None",
  Admin = "Administrator",
  SuperAdmin = "Super Administrator"
}
```

Also see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15486)

Comment: Not tried as it's not released. In typescript 2.4, what's the value of RoleTypes.None, 0 or 'None'?

Comment: I would like RoleTypes.None remains 0, and RoleTypes[RoleTypes.None] has value 'None'. or RoleTypes.SuperAdmin remains value 2 and RoleTypes[RoleTypes.SuperAdmin] has value 'Super Administrator'. Is it possible?

Comment: According to the commit in GH, you can have mixed types for enum, including int and string

Comment: what are you using this with? If you are using something like angular2 or vuejs you can use a pipe/filter as a temporary solution

Comment: @L.W You can always use `next` as TypeScript version (e.g. package.json) to try it out. Now `next` is already 2.5

Answer (score 4):

Combining [Markus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43962328/1366033) with [Use Enum as restricted key type in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243060/1366033), you can use eithers of the following syntaxes to constrain object keys

Either `{ [key in RoleTypes]: string }` or `Record<RoleTypes, string>`

```
enum RoleTypes {
  None,
  Admin,
  SuperAdmin
}

let RoleTypesDisplay: Record<RoleTypes, string> = {
    [RoleTypes.None]: "None",
    [RoleTypes.Admin]: "Administrator",
    [RoleTypes.SuperAdmin]: "Super Admin",
};

var roleName = RoleTypesDisplay[RoleTypes.SuperAdmin];

console.log(roleName);
```

#### [Demo in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9gG2AFQJ4AdgGcoG8CwAUFFAHJwjAA0RJAggCYQCWINxUAymJgE6MsQRAL5EiSAC6xEKDNgAizLOgQBDVAEYAXHigBtANbBUUVtKRpMWALo6sE3qwDmowpPOyri5WtQAmHRhgAGM4XgYAHngLOSwqKHtHECcAPjE3YClozwUlFXVAkLDI7MtseMTnFKgAXjxaEn1S2IA6ckpbKAAiduAu9kammTKsFoFWTq7xkCUHVQkw-oaSPWarFu4+acnN4F4oaaXCYQBudIA3VX3eGVJVCGBajxHvfNRV4dbd-iYJs8JQiAsDIWgg4E4ABQ3JB3B4ASn+QA)

Comment: Is there an easy way to export the `RoleTypesDisplay` as a constant or static collection for re-use?