# Use Enum as restricted key type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Can `enum` be used as a `key` `type` instead of only `number` or `string`? Currently it seems like the only possible declaration is `x:{[key:number]:any}` where key can be of type `number` or `string`. Is it possible to make something like in this example:

Example:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second
}

var layer:{[key:MyEnum]:any};
```

Answer (score 393, accepted):

[Since 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592), there is an easier way in Typescript, without using `keyof typeof`:

```
let obj: { [key in MyEnum]: any} =
 { [MyEnum.First]: 1, [MyEnum.Second]: 2 };
```

To not have to include all keys:

```
let obj: { [key in MyEnum]?: any} =
 { [MyEnum.First]: 1 };
```

To know the difference between `in` and `keyof typeof`, continue reading.

---

### `in Enum` vs `keyof typeof Enum`

**`in Enum` compiles to enum *values* and `keyof typeof` to enum *keys*.**

---

### Other differences

With `keyof typeof`, you **cannot** change the enum properties:

```
let obj: { [key in keyof typeof MyEnum]?: any} = { First: 1 };
obj.First = 1;
// Cannot assign to 'First' because it is a read-only property.
```

... unless you use `-readonly`:

```
let obj: { -readonly [key in keyof typeof MyEnum]?: any} = { First: 1 };
obj.First = 1; // works
```

But you can use any integer key?!:

```
let obj: { [key in keyof typeof MyEnum]?: any} = { First: 1 };
obj[2] = 1;
```

`keyof typeof` will compile to:

```
{
    [x: number]: any;
    readonly First?: any;
    readonly Second?: any;
}
```

Note both the `[x: number]` and the `readonly` properties. This `[x: number]` property doesn't exist with a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums).

But with `in Enum`, you can change the object:

```
enum MyEnum {
    First,  // default value of this is 0
    Second, // default value of this is 1
}

let obj: { [key in  MyEnum]?: any} = { [MyEnum.First]: 1 };
obj[MyEnum.First] = 1; // can use the enum...
obj[0] = 1;            // but can also use the enum value, 
                       // as it is a numeric enum by default
```

It's a [numeric enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums). But we can't use any number:

```
obj[42] = 1;
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 
// expression of type '42' can't be used to index type '{ 0?: any; 1?: any; }'.
// Property '42' does not exist on type '{ 0?: any; 1?: any; }'.
```

The declaration compiles to:

```
{
    0?: any;
    1?: any;
}
```

We allow only `0` and `1`, the values of the enum.

This is in line with how you would expect an enum to work, there are no surprises unlike `keyof typeof`.

It works with [string](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) and [heterogenous](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#heterogeneous-enums) enums:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    First = 1,
    Second = "YES"
}

let obj: { [key in  MyEnum]?: any} = { [MyEnum.First]: 1, [MyEnum.Second]: 2 };
obj[1] = 0;
obj["YES"] = 0;
```

Here the type is:

```
{
    1?: any;
    YES?: any;
}
```

Get immutability with `readonly`:

```
let obj: { readonly [key in MyEnum]?: any} = { 
    [MyEnum.First]: 1,
};
obj[MyEnum.First] = 2;
// Cannot assign to '1' because it is a read-only property.
```

... which makes these keys `readonly`:

```
{
    readonly 1?: any;
    readonly 2?: any;
}
```

---

### Summary

| `in Enum` | `keyof typeof Enum` |
| --- | --- |
| Compiles to enum **values** | Compiles to enum **keys** |
| **Does not allow values outside the enum** | Can allow numeric values outside the enum if you use a numeric enum |
| **Can change the object, immutability opt-in with `readonly`** | Can't change enum props without `-readonly`. Other numeric values outside the enum can be |

**Use `in Enum` if possible.**

Comment: It seems to work great.  When using 'typeof', it looks like, a  key in my object was created from a key of an enum, not a value of this key.

Comment: If i try to define an interface with same structure, it doesn't work. Any idea ?
 https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAHlDeAoKKoEMA0UBGiC%20iiANsAC7rYDGAJgFwJQDaA1sAJ5QCWIsAugPz00IDnigBeBPkKJupYACcAZmkrAuKtVNRNWHbn0HoRAbmmIgA

Comment: "To not have to include all keys:" -> Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Keyof typeof is not equilvalent to key in enum, it creates type that literally consist of keys of enum, not values

Comment: @SachinGupta I ran into the same issue, and it seems that replacing the interface with a type fixes it.
`type Layer = { [key in MyEnum]?: any };` instead of
`interface Layer { [key in MyEnum]?: any }`

Comment: Remember, if you want to create a type for that, then pay attention, that in Typescript you cannot declare mapped type with the `interface` keyword, you can do it only with `type`, because interfaces don't support mapping. Sadly, this fact isn't mentioned explicitly in documentation, at least as of the day of writing this comment. You can find some highlights i.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678970/why-an-interface-cant-have-mapped-properties-in-typescript

Answer (score 139):

Yes. Just type

```
let layer:{[key in keyof typeof MyEnum]: any}
```

The `keyof` keyword is available since Typescript 2.1. See the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) for more details.
Using only `keyof` for enums wouldn't work (you'd get the keys of the `enum` type and not the enum constants), so you have to type `keyof typeof`.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was looking for. Tnx

Comment: @Sebastian but in this case the `value` of layer can be { third: 123 } if we assign it this way: layer.third = 123, can't it? Is it possible to define a type of an object, whose keys can *only* be string keys of an enum (in this case `First` and `Second`)?

Comment: I don't understand. Why whould you be able to add a property "third"?

Comment: And if you don't want all the Enum values to be included forcefully, you can do `{[key in keyof typeof MyEnum]?: any}` (the `?` makes absence of some enums, fine.)

Comment: I have this working within the same file scope where the enum used for the keys is declared. In other files, though, `ENUM_KEY_1` isn't defined. How do I export/import enum _keys_ so that I can reference the object properties?

Comment: not working with me, giving this error `A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'`

Comment: Refer to Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen's answer below. This answer might now in fact be outdated!

Comment: Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen's answer below is indeed better. This one makes all of the properties read only, which is something you might not want.

Answer (score 137):

### Short Answer:

```
let layer: Partial<Record<MyEnum, unknown>>;
```

### Long Answer (with details):

I had the same problem.  I wanted to have the following piece of code work.

```
enum MyEnum {
    xxx = "xxx",
    yyy = "yyy",
    zzz = "zzz",
}

type myType = ...; // Fill here

const o: myType = { // keys should be in MyEnum, values: number
   [MyEnum.xxx]: 2,
   "hi": 5, // <--- Error: complain on this one, as "hi" is not in enum
}

o[MyEnum.yyy] = 8; // Allow it to be modified later
```

Starting from the [other answer](http://share) on this question, I got to:

```
type myType = {[key in keyof typeof MyEnum]: number};
```

But it would nag that `o is missing "yyy"`.  So I needed to tell it that the object is going to have **some** of the enum keys, not all of them.  So I got to add `?` to get:

```
type myType = {[key in keyof typeof MyEnum]?: number};
```

It was working fine, until I added the line at the end of the code to modify the object after its first creation.  Now it was complaining that the type inherited through `keyof` has its properties as `readonly` and I cannot touch them after the first creation! :| In fact, hovering over `myType` in [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play), it will be shown as:

```
type myType = {
    readonly xxx?: number | undefined;
    readonly yyy?: number | undefined;
    readonly zzz?: number | undefined;
}
```

Now, to remove that unwanted `readonly`, I found that I can use:

```
type myType = {-readonly [key in keyof typeof myEnum1]?: number };
```

**Quite ugly, but working**!

Until I played with Typescript [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu), and found what I wanted!

```
type myType = Partial<Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, number>>;
```

:)

Comment: that looks good, but my problem as that all of your `myType` values must have the same type (in your example `number`).

I'd like to be able to do something like:

`type myType = { readonly xxx?: number;  readonly yyy?: string; }`

any idea if that's possible?

Comment: @SudoPlz I'd suggest opening up a new question for that.  The question here is "how to limit the keys to be of an Enum".  Yours is different I believe.  Yet, as a wild guess, either `Partial<Record<MyEnum, number|string>` should work for you or `Partial<Record<MyEnum,number>> | { yyy?: string}`, maybe.

Comment: Nice one but the problem with this solution is that number can be undefined

Comment: @walox Typescript had a problem distinguishing `undefined` and missing/optional -- see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195.  It seems like recently (since a month ago! you can pass a flag to catch it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947)

Answer (score 28):

For those who are seeking for a way to get the `keys` of the `enum` instead its `value`, you just need to change from this:

```
type myType = Partial<Record<MyEnum, number>>;
```

to that:

```
type myType = Partial<Record<keyof typeof MyEnum, number>>;
```

Answer (score 6):

actually it worked with me without any workaround.

here is some cases:

```
enum EnumString {
  a="a",
  b="b"
}

enum EnumNum {
  a,
  b
}

type Type = "a" | "b"


let x1:{[k in EnumString]?:any }={a:1} //working
let x2:{[k in EnumNum]?:any }={a:1} //error: Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ 0?: any; 1?: any; }'
let x3:{[k in Type]?:any }={a:1} //working; defining a union type is easer than defining an enum string 

let y1:{[k: EnumString]?:any }={a:1}
let y2:{[k: EnumNum]?:any }={a:1}
let y3:{[k in Type]?:any }={a:1}

let z1:{[k in keyof typeof EnumString]?:any }={a:1}
let z2:{[k in keyof typeof EnumNum]?:any }={a:1}
let z3:{[k: keyof typeof Type]?:any }={a:1}
```

it is important to note that the case "z1", even it works well, but you cannot modify it later as it is a read only. you can use the keyword `-readonly` to remove this constraint.

```
x1.a=2 
x3.a=2
z1.a=2 //error: read only
```

I created a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEGUAuAnAliA5lA3gKCigEMBeAIiLIBoCoAjcusvAXzz1ElngDkv9CRGoTqt2SAJ4AHYFAAq02SSgUyUAD4qm7ADbAkUAB4BGAFw4A2gGsoGbpGTosAXQD8poiAlQWJHEVNjNj0DQwAmc2tbEHsIPgg3Dy8fPwCgvBCjAGZImzsFGUTPb19-QLYM-SgJM0srU1jHDEwi5NK04KqJCLqGuEh41pLU8sqDCRy66PlFIZSy9LGoAC9aqLsrYAkAewAzKEkZPcbUZrn20czlnvWYzZ39w%20Bj-rjIc5H0q8nrBvvjp7HArAD4LComAB0pDCUDwhiyUJIYTwq0RMIA9OiUMAiAATKDbEA6CTsIA) to see issues of different cases yourself

Answer (score 1):

Summary

```
enum Person {
  FirstName = 'FirstName',
  LastName = 'LastName',
}

// Solution 1
type PersonType1 = { [key in Person]?: string }
const persona1: PersonType1 = {}
persona1[Person.FirstName] = "Bear"
persona1[Person.LastName] = "Belly"
persona1.FirstName = "Bear"
persona1.LastName = "Belly"

// Solution 2
type PersonType2 = Partial<Record<keyof typeof Person, string>>
const persona2: PersonType2 = {}
persona2[Person.FirstName] = "Bear"
persona2[Person.LastName] = "Belly"
persona2.FirstName = "Bear"
persona2.LastName = "Belly"

// Solution 3
type PersonType3 = { -readonly [key in keyof typeof Person]?: string }
const persona3: PersonType3 = {}
persona3[Person.FirstName] = "Bear"
persona3[Person.LastName] = "Belly"
persona3.FirstName = "Bear"
persona3.LastName = "Belly"

// Solution 4 without "-readonly", it does not allow to change.
type PersonType4 = { [key in keyof typeof Person]?: string }
const persona4: PersonType4 = {}
persona4[Person.FirstName] = "Bear" // Cannot assign to 'FirstName' because it is a read-only property.
persona4[Person.LastName] = "Belly" // Cannot assign to 'LastName' because it is a read-only property.
persona4.FirstName = "Bear" // Cannot assign to 'FirstName' because it is a read-only property.
persona4.LastName = "Belly" // Cannot assign to 'LastName' because it is a read-only property.
```

PersonType1, PersonType2, PersonType3 all compile to

```
type PersonTypeX = {
    FirstName?: string | undefined;
    LastName?: string | undefined;
}
```

PersonType4 compiles to

```
type PersonType4 = {
    readonly FirstName?: string | undefined;
    readonly LastName?: string | undefined;
}
```

Hence, you get readonly error.

I personally like solution1. Short enough.