# How to declare a generic type with same keys as an enum?

Tags: typescript

#### Introduction

I have an `enum` and want to map it's values to more descriptive strings. I also want the compiler to recognize when I missed a mapping. So I did something like this:

```js
enum Foo { A, B }

const fooDescriptions: {[key in Foo]: string} = {
    [Foo.A]: 'Option A',
    [Foo.B]: 'Option B',
}
```

*This works as intended*. Now I'd like to declare a more expressive, generic type to replace `{[key in Foo]: string}` (Not that it would be *that* hard to understand, just trying to make things shiny).

My ultimate goal ist a generic type like this

```
type EnumDescriptionType<T> = /* ??? */;
const fooDescriptions: EnumDescriptionType<Foo> = { /* keys of Foo */ };
```

All the following code can also be reproduced on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nKBvKBBANFAQlAvgWACgiBjOEAZwBcoAzBAEWApICcBLAByvfIoC5kAbQDWwAJ5R2IWAgC6g6hxABzXFAC8yIlF1Qh8OADpUCqAHIA8t14zU59Dr0GERrGas3y2B0QLFCKnFOYCgAUXAIJhYOLxAAFWDgAEYAHniAPk1kfTFJaSh4syVpFTwAbiIgkPDI6LYuHnJEkIAmdKytFFEJKRk8uFpC4qplMtxKgLJKGgAbOBIAQ1nDetimymTBCMg1xtsWlNTDTrpGZga4iknp6ih5pZXzmP2+Vu26i-WDpPaT7PocD2V3KQA).

#### Attempt 1

```js
type EnumDescriptionType1<T> = { [key in T]: string };
```

yields error

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

I don't really understand why. I'm used to C++-templates and don't yet fully comprehend the generic type system of typescript.

#### Attempt 2

```js
type EnumDescriptionType2<T> = { [key in keyof T]: string };

const localFooDescriptions2: EnumDescriptionType2<Foo> = fooDescriptions;
```

yields error

```
Type '{ 0: string; 1: string; }' is not assignable to type 'EnumDescriptionType2<Foo>'.
  Type '{ 0: string; 1: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo.B'.
```

At this point I was honestly just trying things without understanding what I did. I would be thankful for clarification.

#### Actual question

I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243060/use-enum-as-restricted-key-type-in-typescript), but they don't use templates. Soooo ...

**... How can I declare a type like `{[key in Foo]: string}`, where `Foo` is a generic parameter that can be replaced with any enum?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure T can be a key, so in the first attempt you can solve the issue by changing it to:

```
type EnumDescriptionType1<T extends keyof any> = { [key in T]: string };
```

Also, a suggestion, you can use the built in `Record` type in this case:

```
type EnumDescriptionType1<T extends keyof any> = Record<T, string>;
```

You can replace the `keyof any` with an explicit `string | symbol | number`, but IMO `keyof any` gives a more readable code in this case.

Comment: In my eyes that's magic, but it works :D Thanks for the quick reply, I will accept it as soon as the system allows it.