# Why an interface can't have mapped properties in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following enum:

```
enum Numbers {
  ONE=1,
  TWO=2
}
```

The following interface definition throws compile-time errors.

```
interface Config {
  [n in Numbers]: string;
}
```

> - A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
> - A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
> - Cannot find name 'n'.

But if I use a type alias:

```
type Config = {
  [n in Numbers]: string;
}
```

Or move the mapped type deeper in the definition:

```
interface Config {
  a: {
    [n in Numbers]: string;
  };
}
```

It compiles just fine.

So, why a top level property of an interface can not be a mapped type?

PS: On [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAcpBGwBOBnKBvAUFKB5GAogLwCMANNlACoDquRATJgL4DcmmAliAC7IBmAQwDGwKAGEA9iH6cA5hkqCAXIpw4A2iCjdYCZCgC6qlDyTc57HG0pad2uBESpjUU+ZCWWHHgE8ADmJSMvIMUERqUHa6js5GJmYW7MwcADbAPFDC0rJyqsG54ZEqkZqxBgB0+ASuAOQAVmCmUNLAtRTqUeWoFbS4dYJQ-oKcSLWUKSmY6ZnZIXIM+TmhRVhl+j3VdY3Nre223Si9dANDI2MsQA) using v4.2.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript does not currently support doing this with interfaces—I’m not sure if there’s a reason for *why* it doesn’t though besides “it hasn’t been implemented”.

Thankfully, this appears to be on the roadmap for TS4.4 via this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797

Edit: As explained in the comments below the above PR doesn’t fully cover the behavior desired in the original question.

Comment: My typical guess for “why does this work with Types but not for Interfaces” is usually “something about interface merging makes this hard”.

Comment: That PR does not pertain to mapped types *per se*, since you can't make the property type depend on the key in an index signature.  A mapped type like `{[P in "foo" | "bar"]: Array<P>`}, which becomes `{foo: "foo"[], bar: "bar"[]}` cannot be accurately represented as an index signature like `{[key: "foo" | "bar"]: Array<???>}`.

Comment: What bothers me most is the fact that moving the mapped type deeper works for the interface

Comment: @Klaimmore moving it deeper works because you’re making it a Type instead of an Interface—all nested fields on interfaces are implicitly defining Types in the background.