# Restrict keys of object to items in passed array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using Typescript I'm looking to restrict the keys of a passed object in a React component to the items in an array thats also passed to the React component:

```
    <MyComponent values={{ dog:true }} items={['dog']} /> // valid

    <MyComponent values={{ dog:true, cat:true }} items={['dog']} /> // invalid - `cat` not in array
```

Can this be solved with generics?

Comment: Check out this answer using enum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243060/use-enum-as-restricted-key-type-in-typescript

Comment: Yes: https://tsplay.dev/WJAavm

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vr. - but is it possible the other way round? Where the keys in "Values" are optional but must appear in the "Items" array?

Comment: Sure, it's a lot simpler: https://tsplay.dev/wQ2OGN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your component generic with respect to `values` and `items`, we can add a condition for the `items` prop where we first check if `keyof Values` is assignable to `Items[number]` (all elements of the array as a union). This is only true if `Items[number]` contains all members of `keyof Values`. TypeScript is also smart enough to infer the type of `Items` through the conditional.

```
function MyComponent<Values extends Record<string, unknown>, Items extends (keyof Values)[]>(props: {
    values: Values;
    items: keyof Values extends Items[number] ? Items : never;
}) { /* ... */ }

// Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
<MyComponent values={{ dog:true, cat:true }} items={['dog']} />;
//                                           ~~~~~
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCswFcA7DYCeuAWQE8BhXSepejAA8ANRQAbWkgDOcJAA8YAgCazkaaMqHSYUYPQDmAGjgMA1vQgB3egD4TASSUhZCpfVVwAFGaQcImHBikjIAlADaALq2XmA4YNIAXHAA3lRwGXAAbhJSSUG5MhSUmXDAzvm+-oHBeXKKKrJOSC7h9LQgAEZIUJFwAPxwzS5wyfxZPcUAvqGpcEQwtFCs7eLicFNUVEKcPOAsAvA5IdIAvCkpcMoQBom6UhtTZRXn4QDk1wZvkU8A9LbFba7XgHQTZQpnC5XG53KBSExoFAwWEPKZPcotSHvT7fP4AqhAA)

---

If you're feeling extra cheeky, you can replace `never` with some helpful error message, perhaps,

```
items: keyof Values extends Items[number] ? Items : `error: key '${Exclude<keyof Values, Items[number]> & string}' is missing`;
```

So then, if you don't provide any keys, you get meaningful errors:

```
// Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '"error: key 'dog' is missing" | "error: key 'cat' is missing"'.
<MyComponent values={{ dog:true, cat:true }} items={[]} />;
//                                           ~~~~~
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCswFcA7DYCeuAWQE8BhXSepejAA8ANRQAbWkgDOcJAA8YAgCazkaaMqHSYUYPQDmAGjgMA1vQgB3egD4TASSUhZCpfVVwAFGaQcImHBikjIAlADaALq2XmA4YNIAXHAA3lRwGXAAbhJSSUG5MhSUmXDAzvm+-oHBeXKKKrJOSC7h9LQgAEZIUJFwAPxwzS5wyQAGPThQyVVwAOQAJCkAovJokspIQlUBBSHSjhVtHd29tnAAZHA6eoYAvnNlsiDA0tL6BmPFd6GpcEQwWhQVjtcTiOB3KhUIScHjgFgCeA5fYAXhSKTgyggBkSuikELuZQqaPCcyxBjmkUJAHpbMVobDeAjBNlCtI0RjybioFITGgUDBufi7oTyi12SkojS6VQgA)