# Store type in interface typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type FilterType = "Filter1" | "Filter2" | "Filter3" | "Filter4" | "Filter5"
let filter: FilterType = "Filter1"
```

Is it possible to store those types into "interface"?

I already tried this but doesn't work

```
interface FilterType {"Filter1" | "Filter2" | "Filter3" | "Filter4" | "Filter5"}
```

Comment: No, interfaces can only represent object types.

Comment: Would maybe [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) be suitable for your usecase?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment but i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112072/5779165) example that seems to fit your needs quite well ?

Comment: @Tommi Thank you, I'll use it as a reference.