# Is it possible to predefine the avaible values of a functions's parameter?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I would like to set the avaible values of a functions parameter something like this:

```
let valueList = [
   'val1',
   'val2',
   'val3',
];

let getSomething = (parameter: valueList) => {
    // do something
}
```

And i want to get error on console if parameter value other than what are in the valueList variable.

And it would be good, if IDE showup the possible values when I call the function as follow:

```
getSomething(| <- cursor ) // when cursor here, the IDE show the possible values from valueList
```

Comment: So you want an *enum*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create enum like type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687793/how-to-create-enum-like-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to document a string type in jsdoc with limited possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093935/how-to-document-a-string-type-in-jsdoc-with-limited-possible-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can define an *enum* as mentioned in other answers or if you want your parameter to be a string, you can use a string literal type combined with union types:

```
type valueList = 'val1' | 'val2' | 'val3';


let getSomething = (parameter: valueList) => {
    // do something
}

getSomething("val1") // OK
getSomething("val1-wrong") // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) for this:

```
enum ValueList {
   val1,
   val2,
   val3
}
```