# How can I generate a type from the properties values of a typed object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Say I had an `interface` that described a library that items that look like this:

```js
interface MyItem {
  category: string,
  title: string
}
```

Now I have a config file full of those MyItems:

```
const myLibrary: MyItem[] = [
  {
    category: "dogs",
    title: "Fuzzy quadrupeds" 
  },
  { 
    category: "snakes",
    title: "Slithery reptiles"
  },
  ...
]
```

Now, I'd like to create a type that consists of all the `category` in `MyItem[]`

If I do this:
`type Category = typeof MyItem[number]["category"]` I get `string`.

If I remove the typing from `myLibrary` (i.e. `const myLibrary = [ {...} ]`) and get what I want:

That means that `type Category = typeof MyItem[number]["category"]` gives me the union type I want of `dogs | snakes` but of course I lose the typing when creating new items in my config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not complicate

```js
type Categorías = 'Food' | 'categoy1' | 'cstegory2'

interface MyItem {
  category: Categories;
  title: string
}

const myLibrary: MyItem[] = [
  {
    category: "dogs",
    title: "Fuzzy quadrupeds" 
  },
  { 
    category: "snakes",
    title: "Slithery reptiles"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing too! I was just hoping for a slicker solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We want to restrict the items in `myLibrary` such that they must implement `MyItem`, but we want to do it in a way that preserves specific types of specific items and doesn't broaden the type to just `MyItem`.

It is hard to do that just with assigning a type to the constant.  A commonly-used pattern is to create the constant through an identity function.  With a function we can use `extends` syntax to ensure that `T extends MyItem[]` while keeping `T` specific.

I had to use `as const` to get the literal category names, so I also had to allow `readonly` in the function arguments.

```
interface MyItem {
  category: string,
  title: string
}

const buildLibrary = <T extends readonly MyItem[]>(library: T): T => library;

const myLibrary = buildLibrary([
  {
    category: "dogs",
    title: "Fuzzy quadrupeds" 
  },
  { 
    category: "snakes",
    title: "Slithery reptiles"
  }
] as const);

type Categories = (typeof myLibrary)[number]['category'] // "dogs" | "snakes"
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NVnZxN)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want this: [How to create enum like type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687793/how-to-create-enum-like-type-in-typescript) and then specify MyItem as

```
interface MyItem: {
    category: MyDogSnakeType,
    title: string
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of the enum route and it might be road I end up going down. I was hoping to avoid having to define the `category` separately when defining all of the different items that might be in library.

Comment: If someone answers with a nicer option, I will be interested ;)